# How to specify the weights in a MixtureModel in Julia Distributions.jl?

Tags: statistics, julia, normal-distribution

In Distributions.jl we can specify the priors of a mixture model. But we cannot specify the weights. For example, if I want to make a mixture like this:

```
pdf(Normal(2, 3), x)*w1.+pdf(Normal(5, 10), x)*w2
```

I cannot really specify the weights. And the priors are required to add up to 1 for obv reasons.
So, **is there a way to specify the weights in MixtureModel?**
Something like:

```
MixtureModel(Normal[
        Normal(2, 3),
        Normal(5, 10)
        ], **weights=[w1, w2]**)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is covered in the Distributions.jl documentation on mixture model constructors — you want the `prior` argument. See

https://juliastats.org/Distributions.jl/v0.14/mixture.html#Constructors-1

Here's a quick plot of their first example.  The `[0.2, 0.5, 0.3]` are the weights:

```
julia> using Distributions, Plots

julia> d = MixtureModel(Normal[
          Normal(-2.0, 1.2),
          Normal(0.0, 1.0),
          Normal(3.0, 2.5)], [0.2, 0.5, 0.3])
MixtureModel{Normal}(K = 3)
components[1] (prior = 0.2000): Normal{Float64}(μ=-2.0, σ=1.2)
components[2] (prior = 0.5000): Normal{Float64}(μ=0.0, σ=1.0)
components[3] (prior = 0.3000): Normal{Float64}(μ=3.0, σ=2.5)


julia> x = -10:0.1:10
-10.0:0.1:10.0

julia> plot(x, pdf.(d, x), legend=nothing, xlabel="x", ylabel="pdf")
```

Which produces

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. My question was what if the weights are not prior probabilities. For example, if it is 0.4 N1 and 0.2 N2. We can then normalize the weights (0.4/0.6) and (0.2/0.6) and use these as prior probabilities. But then we will have to scale the PDF. So the mixture model will have the same shape as the original distribution, but not the same scale.

Comment: I see. There's certainly legitimate reasons for that, though I think this may be out of scope for Distributions.jl itself. See for example the long-standing issue at https://github.com/JuliaStats/Distributions.jl/issues/153. MeasureTheory.jl seems like it attacks this exact problem: https://cscherrer.github.io/MeasureTheory.jl.  But it's more an abstract interface than a toolbox with lots of existing types like mixture models predefined.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The jl community is still evolving, so hopefully there are more tools for more problems in the near future.